# Dry seasoned popcorn in oven

Tags: popcorn

Is there a way to dry homemade seasoned popcorn ?

I used [this recipe](https://tasty.co/recipe/buffalo-popcorn) and the popcorn felt soggy. Can I dry it in the oven ? I am just afraid of the popcorn burning if I put it in the oven at 350F to dry.

Comment: To dry something you would need *LOW* heat. 350 will cook/pop the popcorn, try your oven on the lowest setting and stir the popcorn every 15-20 minutes. That may do it.

Comment: Steve, that seems like a good answer.  Post it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, oven drying is fine. Depending on how much liquid is on the popcorn, 15-30 minutes at 300 F should work. Mix the popcorn around a couple of times during this process.

Keep in mind that hot popcorn will seem soggier than it will be once it cools. When checking for doneness, let a piece cool for a little while before testing it.